# processes and multiple jvm

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

This may be a trivial question and I just want to confirm my understanding on processes and multiple jvms.

I created a C++ dll program calling my java jar file via JNI. I then call this C++ dll in other C++ programs. As far as I know, in any particular program that I call the dll, only one jvm is allowed. In my project, a C++ program calls the dll once at the beginning and the end of the program, and the dll would create jvm when dll is called the first time and attach a thread to jvm when it called the second time.

My question is I will have many different C++ programs calling this dll, so it should create multiple jvms? This is one jvm creation per process, right? Or they are still considered as threads?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A C/C++ program calling into Java APIs will create one JVM per process (when you call `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`) and connect to it.

If you have several instances (processes) of this C/C++ program running, then in that case there is one JVM created for each of those instances.

Each JVM created is a process, not a thread.